# Horizontal scroll inside WP7 pivot page

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, pivot

I'm having problems with horizontal scrolling inside Pivot control in WP7. I have a Grid with ScrollViewer and ten or more buttons inside. Since all buttons don't fit on the screen i need to be able to horizontally scroll. But when i click and drag on buttons the whole Pivot page starts moving and eventually switches to next pivot page. (buttons inside ScrollView also scroll but only for short distance)

Can I somehow disable Pivot page switching when I click inside ScrollView?

Answer (score 3):

It's not a good idea from a user experience perspective to have a horizontal scroll on top of a control that also slides horizontally. I don't know how you'd go about absorbing the manipulation events within the scroll viewer, without affecting the pivot control but, personally, I would rethink the design. Could your ScrollViewer scroll vertically instead, or possibly on another page, but is accessed via the Pivot control?

Comment: I guess i could make a vertical scroll but where is fun in that? :) I was hoping that there's a way to disable pivot scroll when clicking on some controls. For example, when i put horizontal Slider control on page I can drag it left-right without any problems.

Answer (score 2):

I want you to re-evaluate your User experience on this UI since that is not a recommended experience as per the Guidelines. Recommend to consider **Panorama** control for such a case you referring above.

Comment: The Panorama control behaves the same way - drag events are intercepted by the panorama before getting passed to the child control.  I don't know about CyberMuz's app, but I am having the same issue, and in my app it's perfectly appropriate for me to want to handle the drag events within a child control in my panorama, and prevent the panorama from scrolling.  Does anybody else have an answer on this one?

Answer (score 1):

Solution: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/luc/archive/2010/11/22/preventing-the-pivot-or-panorama-controls-from-scrolling.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0

I use this for Slider in Pivot and Pivot in Pivot